# Unexpected ';' in script.. but when i delete T_STRING error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Can anyone explain to me why i get this error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\scripts_for_profile\follow.php on line 10
```

When i try to run this script:

```
<?php
include("/user_sytem_scripts/session.php");
include("/scripts/connect.php");

/* Gets folllowing username */
$following = trim($_GET['user']);
if(!$req_user || strlen($following) == 0 ||
   !preg_match("^([0-9a-z])+$^", $following) ||
/* Gets follower username */
$query = "INSERT INTO follow (follower_username, following_username, time) VALUES ('$session->username', '$following' now())";  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

I am really confused, can anyone help? Because if i remove the ; I get the T_STRING error.

Comment: i think you should take a break and code in the morning

Comment: @Imran Omar Bukhsh how do you know it is not morning for user663049 ?

Comment: cause he seems to be really sleepy to not spot the missing ')'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have left off the end of your `if` statement.

```
   !preg_match("^([0-9a-z])+$^", $following) ||
```

… "does not match this regular expression or" … what?

It resolves the assignment of the string to the `$query` variable as the next "or" and then falls over when it hits the `;` since it was expecting a `)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$req_user || strlen($following) == 0 ||
   !preg_match("^([0-9a-z])+$^", $following) || //here missing condition and ){ 
 // or extra ||
 /* Gets follower username */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not closed:

```
if(!$req_user || strlen($following) == 0 ||
    !preg_match("^([0-9a-z])+$^", $following))
```